# How blacklist imports in a specific file with tslint

Tags: angular, tslint

Does TSLint support blacklisting imports in specific files? If yes how can I configure it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no default rule that can achieve this. But TSLint can be extended with custom rules. Here is a good tutorial on how to create, include and use custom rules https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/.

We can start with the existing `import-blacklist` rule and extend it. To original source can be found at [importBlacklistRule.ts](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/fb0da64bcf7607ae2122c8485cc7bde2ed6895da/src/rules/importBlacklistRule.ts)

We just need to extend the options to include file-names and have to check the filename. Here a complete listing:

```js
import * as Path from "path";
import * as Lint from "tslint";
import { findImports, ImportKind } from "tsutils";
import * as TS from "typescript";

interface Options {
  imports: string[];
  files: string[];
}

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
  public static FAILURE_STRING =
    "This import is blacklisted, import a submodule instead";

  public apply(sourceFile: TS.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
    return this.applyWithFunction(sourceFile, walk, this
      .ruleArguments[0] as Options);
  }
}

const walk = (ctx: Lint.WalkContext<Options>) => {
  if (ctx.options.files === undefined || ctx.options.imports === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  const fileName = Path.basename(ctx.sourceFile.fileName); // Strip off path
  if (ctx.options.files.indexOf(fileName) === -1) {
    // Could be extended to test for a regex.
    return;
  }

  for (const name of findImports(ctx.sourceFile, ImportKind.All)) {
    if (ctx.options.imports.indexOf(name.text) !== -1) {
      ctx.addFailure(
        name.getStart(ctx.sourceFile) + 1,
        name.end - 1,
        Rule.FAILURE_STRING
      );
    }
  }
};
```

In the example above I have stripped down the `import-blacklist` rule to its essentials and added a check for the filename.

```js
const fileName = Path.basename(ctx.sourceFile.fileName); // Strip off path
if (ctx.options.files.indexOf(fileName) === -1) {
    // Could be extended to test for a regex.
    return;
}
```

In the example, we only check, that the filename without the path must be present in `options.files`. You could extend this logic to check for a regex or whatever fits your needs.

While including this rule you have to specify the filenames to check and the prohibited imports.

```
"custom-import-blacklist": [
  true,
  {
    "files": ["Index.ts"],
    "imports": ["xxx"]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: Is there an existing NPM package for that?

Comment: @MaximeGélinas I don't think there is. But if you need this. The listing is complete, just copy it to your project.